# Change hbase timestamp sorting in order to get the first version of specific row

Tags: java, hbase, nosql

According to my requirements I need to get the first version of specific row in Hbase. Suppose the following Htable:

```
row_key          cf1:c1           timestamp
----------------------------------------
1                  x                 t1
1                  x                 t2
1                  x                 t3
...
```

Suppose I want to retrieve the first version of row(1) according to timestamp.
First, is there any hbase java method for this purpose?
Second, if there is not such method can I change the sorting order of timestamp to DESC for retrieving such cell by getting the last version of row(1)? What is the concerns of doing this change to timestamp ordering of hbase?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Result.getColumnCells](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Result.html#getColumnCells(byte[],%20byte[])) to get all the columns and then get the first one from the list.

Possible alternative solutions:

- store the first value in a separate column. This will require different code for inserting and updating the cell though.
- manually set timestamp to `Long.MAX_VALUE - System.currentTimeMillis()`. In this case make sure that the maximum number of versions for a cell is high enough otherwise the latest values will be garbage collected by HBase.
- store timestamp as part of the row key and get the first value using Scan with PageFilter.

Comment: It is too costly for me since it should be done per each get request!

Comment: Have you measured the difference in performance? It still might be fast enough. There are other possible ways to implement it but they all have their drawbacks. I will update the answer.

Comment: So there is no way to change the default behavior of Hbase to sort timestamp in descending order?

Comment: As far as I know - no. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? It is possible that it can be solved by using HBase in a different way.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at scan.setReverse(true)? A side note, it's not available in older versions (we use 0.94.18) and is one of motivations for us to upgrade.

Comment: If I understand correctly setReverse(true) allows to iterate over row keys in reverse order and the question was about reversing order of cell versions. One of my suggestions was to make a timestamp part of row key. In this case setReverse might be useful.

Comment: KeyValueScanner.java

"Seek the scanner at the first Cell of the row which is the previous row of specified key"

My understanding is that first Cell is the Cell with first timestamp.

Comment: Maybe you are right, it's quite easy to test. Lets leave this task to the original poster ;)

Comment: Sure, I wish I could test myself but I'm on 0.94 which doesn't have reverse scanners.